# How to get audio data from the Macbook microphone?

Tags: cocoa, audio, core-audio

I am looking to write a small audio processing program, and I need some way to get audio input from the microphone in a Macbook.

Buffer polling? Notifications? What class/framework should I be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one of the easiest ways is with audio queues. its fairly abstracted, with a fair bit of doco and examples, simpler than delving into audio units, and the depths of core audio.

[here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the official link.

Answer (score 2):

Use Core Audio: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html